# Create a nested object strictly using a for-loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, linked-list, frontend

So, I already know how to do this using recursion.  However, I wanted to create my singly linked list strictly using a for-loop. I need to write ansList then ansList.next then ansList.next.next ... etc  i.e. I want something like this)

```
let ansList = new ListNode(ansArr[0]);
let n = next;
for (let i =1; i<=ansArr.length;i++) {      
    let x = ansList + n**i;
    x = new ListNode(ansArr[i]);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListNode = function(parent)
{
  this.parent = parent;
}

var first = new ListNode();
var next = first;
for (let i =1; i<=10;i++)
      next = new ListNode(next);

console.log(next);
```

Comment: function ListNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
};